# WCF Services: Requests are limited to a single "Request" Paramater

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a very strange and obscure issue with WCF services that I was hoping to get some insight on:

I am working a WCF service that we are building to replace one that we no longer have source code for. For some reason, in the new WCF service, everything is forced through a single paramater called "request". Using the WCF test client, this is what it looks like

[image: Request is forced under request paramater]

On the "correct" service, this is what it looks like:

[image: Correct WCF schema]

Is there any reason why this would be happening? I've defined all of the requests as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
        [OperationContract]
        string SomeRequest();
}
```

Which seems correct, but there may be something I've overlooked that is causing this.

Comment: Hi,
May I know how is the issue going on now?
If you do not have any other concerns, please remember to mark the answer.

Comment: It ultimately had to do with a very obscure issue, our "model" classes defined a special dict type that caused this. Removing our custom dict type caused the normal behavior

I'll post an answer when I get back!

Answer (score 0):

In your original WCF service, there is a request function parameter, and it has a definition similar to the following:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Request SomeRequest(Request request);
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Request
    {
        string documentId;


        [DataMember]
        public string DocumentId
        {
            get { return documentId; }
            set { documentId = value; }
        }
    }
```

In the new wcf service:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SomeRequest(string documentId);
    }
```

So this is because the function parameters are different. Originally your parameter was class, but later changed to string, so the display in WCFTestClient is different.